# Display a value zero in input control when the object is null in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am writing a angular 4 application. When the drop down is not selected , I need to show the value zero in the input control. I guess there are mainly two ways of doing it. The first way would be to initialize the array value with zero and bind it to input control or use two input controls on the UI. One that will display when the object is null and value on the screen will contain zero the other would display the value based on selection of the drop down. I am trying to implement using the first method but getting an error  "Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined". Could somebody show me the easier way to achieve it.

```
<div *ngIf="fedExTax" class="col-lg-3 col-6 mb-3">
        <label class="col-form-label">{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey|uppercase|translate}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="fedExTax.value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
            name="{{FedExciseKey}}" numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2" (ngModelChange)="change()" [required]="true" tooltip="{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey + 'TOOLTIP'|uppercase|translate}}"
            placement="bottom">
          <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="!fedExTax" class="col-lg-3 col-6 mb-3">
        <label class="col-form-label">{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey|uppercase|translate}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" [value]="0" 
            name="{{FedExciseKey}}" numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2" [required]="true" tooltip="{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey + 'TOOLTIP'|uppercase|translate}}"
            placement="bottom">
          <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Component code

```
 get fedExTax(): BackendDto.FedExciseExpense {
    if (this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy !== 0) {
      return this.fedExciseExpensesInputs.find(x => x.coveragePolicyTypeId === this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy && x.is953D === this.currentSelected953D);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of `fedExTax.value` to 0 in your component and then you will only need the one field definition. Since your getter returns null you cannot access the `value` property of `fedExTax` in the view. Modify the getter to return a default object if the fedExTax can't be found.

```js
 get fedExTax(): BackendDto.FedExciseExpense {
   if (this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy !== 0) {
     return this.fedExciseExpensesInputs.find(x => x.coveragePolicyTypeId === this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy && x.is953D === this.currentSelected953D);
   }
   return { value: 0 } as BackendDto.FedExciseExpense;
 }
```

Comment: Do i need to change get fedExTax() property as i am getting the same error. I tried removing return of null but no difference

Comment: What i feel is happening is that fedExTax doesnt get set hence is undefined

Comment: Is `fedExTax` a getter? Ex `public get fedExTax() { return this._fedExTax; }`

Comment: I tried this but getting the same error  public get fedExTax(): BackendDto.FedExciseExpense {
    if (this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy !== 0) {
      return this.fedExciseExpensesInputs.find(x => x.coveragePolicyTypeId === this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy && x.is953D === this.currentSelected953D);
    }
    return this._fedExTax;
  }